# Providing link to background url html

Tags: html

I am setting up a new app on GoodBarber and using the html section as I want to be able to more personalize my app.  However, I am trying to set a background to a section and it will not display the file that I had uploaded to Google Drive as my background.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    body {
    background-image: url(https://images.app.goo.gl/16UbvTJEEPf8AuNG9);
    }
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  Firstly, you need to include your CSS within your `<style>` tag.

```
<style>
  body {
    background-image: ...
  }
</style>
```

The next issue is that the URL you're using isn't actually an image at all.  It's a link to a page with images on it.  The actual image URL is https://images.pexels.com/photos/457882/pexels-photo-457882.jpeg.  You can find that by right clicking the image on the page and opening the image in a new tab, then copying the URL.

Once you use the right URL, and put your CSS in the right place, it will work fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/nx4wc8pd/